# cordova camera plugin allowEdit property not working in few phones

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I have developed a cordova app where I'm using Cordova camera plugin(https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html) for taking images from the phone via camera or gallery and crop according to a fixed frame size to save on the server. But when the user selects an image from the gallery the cropping tool not working for certain phones like phones of Redmi Note 4, Redmi Note 3, Redmi 3S Prime, LeTv phones though I have given "allowEdit:true".

JS Code:-

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
        }, {
        //quality: 99,
        quality: 25,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit: true,
        targetWidth: 0,
        targetHeight: 0
        });
```

How should I go ahead to solve this cropping issue?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs

> **allowEdit** is unpredictable on Android and it should not be used! The Android implementation of this plugin tries to find and use an
>   application on the user's device to do image cropping. The plugin has
>   no control over what application the user selects to perform the image
>   cropping and it is very possible that the user could choose an
>   incompatible option and cause the plugin to fail. This sometimes works
>   because most devices come with an application that handles cropping in
>   a way that is compatible with this plugin (Google Plus Photos), but it
>   is unwise to rely on that being the case. If image editing is
>   essential to your application, consider seeking a third party library
>   or plugin that provides its own image editing utility for a more
>   robust solution.

So, basically don't use it as it's not guaranteed to work as it needs an external app to do the crop and not all devices will have it.

Comment: I tried to use cordova-plugin-crop to crop the image, but still its not working. can you please help me how can I use this plugin?

Comment: Accept this answer and create a new one about the cordova-plugin-crop providing the code you are using

Comment: Totally unpredictable feature. One time I had a problem with a cordova app where on ios everything was ok with file uploading and allowedit, but on android I received CORS errors on upload. Set allowedit to false and the uploads on android also started working. Hope I saved someone some time searching ;)